# How to copy a collection without using a loop?

Tags: java, collections, deep-copy

I wonder if there are any methods available to deep copy a collection rather than use Iterator to loop it through? I can't downcast it since my method take a parameter like `Collection<Something> something`. Thanks.

Comment: You mean _without **me** looping through_, right? Otherwise the answer is: Impossible due to the fact that you (or the "utility" function) need to iterate over all elements in order to copy them.

Answer (score 1):

No built in method in Java allows to make a deep copy for a collection for an simple reason : the definition of a deep copy depends on the class.
No utility method can guess it and relying on `Cloneable` that is not a recommended interface would be not a good idea.
So you have to do this task yourself.

You could make things more generic by introducing an interface that defines a copy method that each class to deep copy implements.
For example :

```
public interface Copyable<T> {

   T copy();
}
```

And implement it such as :

```
public class Foo implements Copyable<Foo> {

   public Foo copy(){
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      // deep copy values in foo
      return foo;
   }
}
```

And you could introduce a `static` method in `Copyable` to perform the deep collection copy :

```
public static <T extends Copyable<T>> List<T> deepCopyToList(Collection<T> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .map(Copyable::copy)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And use it in this way :

```
List<Foo> foos = new ...;
List<Foo> fooCopies = Copyable.deepCopyToList(foos);
```

Where `Foo` implements `Copyable`.

Comment: Or `List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(collection); result.replaceAll(Copyable::copy);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use addAll to create a copy of the original collection.